# How to programmatically add to cart with order comment history in Magento

Tags: magento

How can I programmatically add an item to the cart along with some predefined text that would appear in the comment history once ordered?
This predefined text comment shouldn't be editable by the customer. It's essentially used as meta information about the order item that the person fulfilling it will need to know about.

If this is not possible, is there any other way I can attach the predefined text to the cart for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution...

When adding to cart, get the quote item id,  then create a text file on disk with the quote item id as the file name.  Serialise the data you need store into this file.  Then create a observer for sales_order_place_before  event .  The quote item id will be passed to that event, so you can reference that text file.

Don't use a session to store the data, as cart items will remain even if the user logs out and then logs back in later.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something similar, but not exactly the same...

I've created a module where I'm adding some new custom values to the quote when adding a new product to the cart

In the module, I've an observer when:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <mymodule_addtocart_observer>
                    <class>mymodule_addtocart/observer</class>
                    <method>myMethod</method>
                </mymodule_addtocart_observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
```

and in my observer I update my quote

```
public function myMethod(Varien_Event_Observer $obs) {
        $item = $obs->getQuoteItem();
        $quote = $item->getQuote();
        $quote->setData("myattribute", "myvalue");  
}
```

I guess you can do the same updating your item in the observer.

Hope it helps...

Comment: I tried this,  but I can't see where "myattribute"  shows up in the order. I'm looking at the order though the admin

Comment: In my module I have created the attribute value in the SQL table first: `$installer->run("
        ALTER TABLE '{$installer->getTable('sales/quote')}' ADD 'myattribute' int DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Description of my attribute';
");`

Answer (score 0):

The best way for me should be to create a product attribute for this meta informations, and display the attribute value into a custom adminhtml theme on the view order page (or view shipment i dont know).
This way you don't have to create observers, order item attributes, ...
The downside is that if you update the informations in your product, the value will also be updated in past orders. Depending of what you want this can be a problem.

Comment: The text that I need to add will be different for every order.  Would your solution work in that scenario?

Comment: No that would be the same text for all orders.
So you need do to something with events/observers and save the data in the quote_item / order_items. You should find articles on stackoverflow avout creating custom order item attributes